# contour plot (cartesian) using spherical coordinates postions

Tags: plotting

Let´s say that I have a data in the following configuration: { Lat, Long,distance, energy}-> lat, long -> galactic coordinates, distance unit - parsecs (3.2 ly)
energy unit- ergs.

I need to plot them as a contourplot like that

(figure1):

[image: contourplot energies- figure 1]

The steps:

The original array: [dat1.dat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bywf7dc535e502/dat1.dat?dl=0)

```
{{lat, long, distance, energy},....}
```

Then I transformed lat, long , in cartesian coordinates, so the  list has now 2 cartesian coordinates  and energy as third element( "z" is the energy value) :

```
$dat1 = Import["/home/.............../dat1.dat"]       
mapdados3={#[[3]]*1000 *Cos[#[[1]]* Pi/180]*Cos[#[[2]]* Pi/180], #[[3]]*1000*Cos[#[[1]]* Pi/180] *Sin[#[[2]]* Pi/180], #[[3]]} & /@ $dat1
```

Note: I did the multiplication for **1000**, just for scale issues.

I did a plot like the frame of figure 1 (not yet the contours , ok?):

```
ListPlot[mapdados3[[All, {1,2}]], FrameLabel -> {"Long Galactic", "Long Galactic"}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{{{0, 180 \[Degree]}}, {{0, 0 \[Degree]}}},
  {{{0, 270 \[Degree]}}, {{0, 90 \[Degree]}}} } ]
```

figure 2:

[image: galactic map]

Each curve in figure 1 is a decade ranging from 10^34 to 10^36 ergs/[100pc^2].

I did a contour plot for testing (it was terrible!!):

```
ListContourPlot[mapdados3, DataRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Mesh -> 100]
```

figure 3:

[image: contourplot]

My question is: How Do I include the ploting data in a listcontourplot , using the frame of figure 1 and 2 and taking in account the range from 10^34 to 10^36 ergs? Why is my contour so wrong?

UPDATE: 1

```
 ListContourPlot[mapdados3, ContourShading -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

Figure 4

[image: contourplot test2]

UPDATE2:

Some improvements:

a. first I did a new cartesian plotting.

```
marker1 = Graphics[{Lighter[Blue, 0.1], Disk[]}];
ListPlot[mapdados3[[All, {1, 2}]], PlotMarkers -> {marker1, .006}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3000, 3000}, {-3000, 3000}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Long Galactic", "Long Galactic"}, Frame -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 GridLines -> {Table[i, {i, -3000, 3000, 100}], 
   Table[i, {i, -3000, 3000, 100}]},
 FrameTicks -> {{{{0, 180 \[Degree]}}, {{0, 0 \[Degree]}}},
                             {{{0, 270 \[Degree]}}, {{0, 
      90 \[Degree]}}}}, Ticks -> {{0, 1000, 2000}, {0, 1000, 2000}}
                        ]
```

Figure 5

[image: Plot points]

b. A new contour plot changing the scales, but not so good. It seems that the contour lines is taking points very far awy, is there a way to rule that only point closer than xxx units, could be considered to do a certain contour?

```
ListContourPlot[mapdados3, ContourShading -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3000, 3000}, {-3000, 3000}}, 
 Contours -> {10^34, 10^35, 10^36, 10^37, 10^38}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 5, AspectRatio -> 3/4]
```

Figure 6

[image: Contourplot3]

UPDATE 3.

I used maxPlotPoints, reducing the range of axis scale:

```
   mapdados4 = 
 DeleteCases[
  mapdados3, {a_, p_, r_} /; 
   a >= 3000 || a <= -3000 || p >= 3000 || p <= -3000, Infinity]
```

figure 7:
[image: plot maxPlot]

UPDATE 3: finally!

I did a contour map, 'similar" figure 1, but the  distances points far away are connected.

this is the code:

data : [[http://1drv.ms/1JuEF4L]](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6we72bp8f7emjwk/Mapa_Obs.dat?dl=0)[9](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6we72bp8f7emjwk/Mapa_Obs.dat?dl=0)

```
 $tudo =data

mapdados3Obs = Sort[{#[[8]] *Cos[#[[7]]* Pi/180]*Cos[#[[6]]* Pi/180], #[[8]]*Cos[#[[7]]* Pi/180] *Sin[#[[6]]* Pi/180], #[[4]]} & /@ $tudo];

Show[ListContourPlot[mapdados3Obs, PlotRange -> {5*10^34, 2*10^37}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ContourShading -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 1,(*PlotLegends->Automatic,*)ContourStyle -> Blue, MaxPlotPoints -> 200, Contours -> Function[{min, max}, Range[min, max, (max - min)/17]], FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {" long galactica (\[Degree])", Style[" 10 Contornos", 12, "Panel"]}}, ImageSize -> Medium, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{0, 18 \[Degree]}, { 0, 0 \[Degree]}}, {{0, 27 \[Degree]}, {0, 90 \[Degree]}}}], ListPlot[{{0, 0}}, PlotMarkers -> {
    {Graphics[{Yellow, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], 0.008}}]]
```

and the contour:

[image]

Comment: Thanks bbgodfrey, My firefox had  some bug that did not allow me use the math code formatting.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the download, but try removing `DataRange -> All` from the final plot. I think that's confusing `ListContourPlot`.

Comment: Hi I did some progress, removing datarange, and contourshading -None. Please see the update 1

Comment: Thanks SquareOne, I did the corrections, and one update,  but I choose the extension .dat, ok?

Comment: Why don't you plot `$dat[[All, ;;3]]` directly, instead of running the conversion? The plots on pg 5 of [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4061.pdf) does just that.

Comment: Make that `dat1[[All, {2, 1, 3}]]` to get latitude and longitude in their correct spots.

Comment: Hi rcollyer, which plot do you mean?

Comment: Right, there are two plots there. In the upper left corner of page 5, there are a set of 4 contour plots where the x and y directions are angles.

Comment: ok!See, that, I can`t use lat, as my contour is in 2 d, using only the references : glactic long and energies (as "elevations"), Latitude is projected onto a plane.

Comment: @locometro Two problems:  1/ `mapdados3` contains a point whose x coordinate is about 20000, so it is >>> than the rest of the x's. You can see that if you run `ListPlot[mapdados3[[All, {1, 2}]], PlotRange -> All]`. 2/ What exactly do you want to show/interpolate with the `ContourPlot` ? I mean look at the energy ("z") distribution here : `ListPointPlot3D[mapdados3]` ...

Comment: @locometro By the way in `mapdados3` the third component should indeed be `#[[4]]` as you first set it.

Comment: Dear Square, 1 - yes there is a point out of range, so is there away for not considering it, inside the command ListContourPlot? I want to show contours of energies, so I think the interpolation must be through "z" points. See my update3.

Comment: @locometro Look carefully to `ListPointPlot3D[mapdados4, PlotRange -> All]`: can you see that many times there are group of points with very close  x,y coordinates but with very different energies ... How would you interpolate that ?

Comment: Yes, this  is  the point... I think in averaging  squares of 100 pc^2, and then using theses grids.

Comment: moving mouse over the contours, the result is always 0...